# Opening UDP Ports

Tags: 14.04, networking, server

I'm trying to open a port which I believe I did but maybe It didn't work.

I'm trying to run a server of Counter Strike 1.6 and its Online however Its not responding when I try to refresh data about the server. I also tried to check and It fails with quering the ports as you can see here:

[image]

I'm assuming that It has something with the ports, I opened them using this command:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 27000:27030 --dport 1025:65355 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 4380 --dport 1025:65355 -j ACCEPT
```

I then tried to run nmap to see what ports are actually opened but It didn't seem like they are open:

[image]

Comment: What NMAP command did you use?

Comment: NMAP ip_address

Comment: What is the output of `nmap -p- ip_address`?

Comment: @Robby1212 http://i.imgur.com/4rYmZrm.png

Comment: Huh, well those ports definitely aren't open that much is for sure.

Comment: So how to open the 27015 exactly and why the command I posted didn't work.

Comment: If you run the following `ufw allow 27000:27030/udp` and then run the `nmap -p- ip_address` does it show that those ports are open, you can replace the port numbers as needed.

Comment: Where are you putting those IPtables?

Comment: I did run the command like you said but the output is the same as this one: http://i.imgur.com/4rYmZrm.png 
As for IPTables, I'm not really sure honestly, I'm not much of a Ubuntu expert, was simply following a tutorial In order to get the server running.

Comment: Can you link the tutorial please?

Comment: Did you run the ufw allow command with `sudo`?

Comment: Tried with and without sudo, same thing.
Tutorial: https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-counter-strike-1-6-server-linux (where I got the ports things from)
otherwise I followed this for everything else but there are no mention for opening ports here: https://nscodes.com/install-counter-strike-1-6-server-linux/ (check the Ubuntu tab and not the CentOS one)

Comment: Without the context of your entire iptables rules set, we can not tell if those commands will work or not. Also, should it be the destination port you allow, not the source port? I'm suggesting the command should be this: `iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 27000:27030 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: I did run your command, didn't have any messages as output. I ran nmap afterwards, I got the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `iptables` rules by add `multiport`

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --match multiport --sport 27000:27030 --dport 1025:65355 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --match multiport --sport 4380 --dport 1025:65355 -j ACCEPT
```

And maybe is better to only have destination port [if you do not do port forwarding].

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --match multiport --dport 1025:65355 -j ACCEPT
sudo sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --match multiport --dport 1025:65355 -j ACCEPT
```

You can check connection on `udp` port with `nc`

```
sudo nc -v -z -u <ip_address_of_server> <port>
```

You will get output, something like in my example connection on port `69` aka `tftp`

```
xxx@yyy~$ nc -u -v -z 10.10.10.10 69
Connection to 10.10.10.10 69 port [udp/tftp] succeeded!
```

Complete `iptables1 rules will be

Disable `UFW`

```
sudo uwf disable
```

Delete curent rules and chains in `iptables`

```
sudo iptables --flush
sudo iptables --delete-chain
```

allow loopback

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

drop `ICMP`

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type any -j DROP
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j DROP
```

allow established connections

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Allow `UDP` ports

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --match multiport --sport 27000:27030 --dport 1025:65355 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --match multiport --sport 4380 --dport 1025:65355 -j ACCEPT
```

allow `SSH` or some different `TCP` port

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

default policies

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Save

```
sudo iptables-save
```

This is it. I think :)